# C# VS WP8 Linking a created tile to a Uri Scheme

Tags: hyperlink, windows-phone-8, uri, tiles, homescreen

First i create a tile with this code:

```
private void btnIconicTile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IconicTileData oIcontile = new IconicTileData();
        oIcontile.Title = "Hello Iconic Tile!!";
        oIcontile.Count = 7;

        oIcontile.IconImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/Iconic/202x202.png", UriKind.Relative);
        oIcontile.SmallIconImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/Iconic/110x110.png", UriKind.Relative);

        oIcontile.WideContent1 = "windows phone 8 Live tile";
        oIcontile.WideContent2 = "Icon tile";
        oIcontile.WideContent3 = "All about Live tiles By WmDev";

        oIcontile.BackgroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black;

        // find the tile object for the application tile that using "Iconic" contains string in it.
        ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("Iconic".ToString()));

        if (TileToFind != null && TileToFind.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("Iconic"))
        {
            TileToFind.Delete();
            ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?id=Iconic", UriKind.Relative), oIcontile, true);
        }
        else
        {
            ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?id=Iconic", UriKind.Relative), oIcontile, true);//
        }
    }
```

Now i want that the created tile in the homescreen links to an app (Uri Scheme?) like this on for ex:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("whatsapp:"));
```

How i can modify the "link" of that recently created tile?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i need too.

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("whatsapp:"))
```

homescreen

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.